# Menu key for android keyboard

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I'm in the process of creating my own keyboard. I need help finding out the android:codes number for the menu button so I can implement the zoom function. Thank you.

Comment: [You mean this one?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MENU) I just googled for "android code number menu key"

Comment: From that it says: Key code constant: Menu key.

Constant Value: 82 (0x00000052). However, the constant 82 is not the same when i put it onto android studio.

Comment: What do you mean "the constant 82 is not the same when i put it onto android studio"?

Comment: http://puu.sh/o6lzA/a336780062.png 82 is an uppercase R, so my question is how would i get android studio to recognize 82 and not the ACII number. Also, would it be possible to implement zoom+i in one key?

Answer (score 0):

The menu key for Android keyboard is constant value 82 which if you're using the emulator can be triggered using `Ctrl + M`.

A good way to test this is to override the dispatchKeyEvent() method which is used in any Activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent: " + event.getKeyCode());
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Whenever you press `Ctrl + M` while having that Activity open it'll trigger that dispatchKeyEvent method which will print out: `D/YourActivity: dispatchKeyEvent: 82`